# Plot a vertical line at the minimum/maximum value in a time series plot

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot a vertical line at the point of a min/max (or other) value in a `xts` plot.  I have the location or row number of the minimum value. I don't know how to translate that to the date object which is used in `abline()`.

Here is a simple version of the code:

```
dates <- as.Date("2016-01-01") + 0:9
library(xts)
ts <- xts(rnorm(10), order.by = dates)

minv <- which.min(ts[,1])
```

This gives me the location of the minimum. What I need is the numeric value of the date at that location for the following

```
library(zoo)
plot.zoo(ts, plot.type="s")
abline(v=as.numeric(DateOfMinValue))
```

How do I get `DateofMinValue` which is in row `minv`? or have I missed a step? or is there a package that accomplishes this more easily.

Comment: `DateOfMinValue <- dates[minv]` ?

Comment: `abline(v = as.numeric(time(ts)[minv]))`