# Add Horizontal Line to xts Plot

Tags: r, plot, xts

I would like to add a *horizontal* line to an xts object plot.  I know there is the `addEventLines()` function in `xts` to add vertical lines, but the following does not add a line to an `xts` plot:

```
abline(h=abc, col="green")
```

Is there a workaround for this other than adding a new column to the object itself before plotting?

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45331314/plot-a-vertical-line-at-the-minimum-maximum-value-in-a-time-series-plot ?

Comment: Also you should post an example of your data to help with the answer.

Comment: @RLave yes, I know I can use the `plot.zoo()` function, but since my data is in `xts` format it would be much easier to plot using the built-in `plot.xts()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create some constant data and use the `lines` function. Below is a solution together with a reproducible example.

```
# load package
require(xts)

# get data
data(sample_matrix)
sample.xts <- as.xts(sample_matrix)

# create line data
sample.xts$horizontal_line <- 49.5

# plot 
plot(sample.xts[,"Close"])
lines(sample.xts[, "horizontal_line"], col = "blue")
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, if it is acceptable to create another entire data series.  I actually broke down and regressed to using `plot.zoo()` as I had done in the past.  It takes significantly longer to set up, but is much better for customization.  The function is able to interact with other built-in functions (`legend`, `abline`, etc.).